# Possible to create a Bash alias that enters a certain string into Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, alias

Is it possible to create a Bash alias that upon running, enters a string of my prior choosing, into Terminal?

Let's pretend this is in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias start_youtube="cd ~/Video/Youtube; **[PASTE: youtube-dl URL]**"
```

Imagine that: the alias would change directory to `Video/Youtube` and then **[PASTE]** the string: `youtube-dl URL`. It could either do <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd> or preferably just leave the string `youtube-dl URL` in the Terminal prompt so that I could swap the placeholder URL for a real URL.

If I try actually running the alias below;

```
alias start_youtube="cd ~/Video/Youtube; youtube-dl URL"
```

it will run the command as entered by which youtube-dl will return an error like *"Could not parse URL"* – which could've been fine. But pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> key will not show the last input of the alias (`youtube-dl URL`) but rather shows the invoking of the alias (`start_youtube`) [which I'm sure is usually preferable].

So the requested solution is to paste a placeholder string into the Command Prompt, or somehow access the history of the alias command via the Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it. Use [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function) to write the function that would reside in your `bashrc` or `bash_profile`. Then add a line in the function that would delete the most recent line in your bash history [using this](https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file#384383)

Comment: I settled for something inbetween. Created a function that *`echo`es* the "placeholder string" which I can Copy, Edit and Enter, once the alias has `cd` to the desired dir. Didn't understand how to access bash history from the alias or why to delete lines from it, because keyboarding ↑ does not reveal the commands used in the alias afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `osascript` for this and tell the System Events to type keys for you. **Generally, I strongly advise against the whole approach of blindly sending keystrokes to the shell, you can wreak havoc on your system with this!**

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "# cd /tmp; your text" '
```

For safety reasons I send the comment character `#` as the first character, but this line gives the result you wanted. The cursor waits after the *your text* and you may continue typing.